# Search fails to find matching issues

Tags: bug, search

When I search for the string `"cwlogs.push.reader" "reason: timestamp could not be parsed from message"` on Google, one of the top results is the following Stack Overflow question: *[AWS Clouwatch logs agent (awslogs) going crazy and writing GBs to log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154448/aws-clouwatch-logs-agent-awslogs-going-crazy-and-writing-gbs-to-log-file)*

However, when I then attempt to search for the same terms in Stack Overflow, I get [no results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22cwlogs.push.reader%22%20%22reason%3A%20timestamp%20could%20not%20be%20parsed%20from%20message%22). Even when I simply search for `"timestamp could not be parsed from message"`, I still get [0 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22timestamp%20could%20not%20be%20parsed%20from%20message%22). I would expect to see  *[AWS Clouwatch logs agent (awslogs) going crazy and writing GBs to log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154448/aws-clouwatch-logs-agent-awslogs-going-crazy-and-writing-gbs-to-log-file)* in the results at the *very least*, but even it doesn't show up. I wonder if there are other matching questions that are not being returned?

Comment: This gives you no results: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=timestamp+could+not+be+parsed+from+message ?  Because it gives me 51 results and number 4 is the one you mention specifically.

Comment: It is *odd*. Two of those words quoted returns nothing yet two other words works: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22cwlogs%22+%22timestamp%22&mixed=0  **vs**  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22this%22+%22that%22&mixed=0

Comment: @RageFoxx: Note the quotes in the search string

Comment: @Katie I did, but I was curious if the results were not there without quotes.  Because I used what you searched and found what you were after.  Exact matching likely doesn't read code blocks is my best guess.

Comment: In this case, [if you prefix the term with](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22reason%3A+timestamp+could+not+be+parsed+from+message%22) `code:` it is the first result. that should hint as to why this isn't working without `code:`

Comment: @everyone Asked and answered on [SO meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393260/3648282). Katie, when you ask the exact same question on more than one site you should include a link in your question.